# Get post id from url and feed it to my wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, get

I have a page where users can anonymously submit posts with USP Pro and the post has to wait for approval. I would like to give them a confirmation text with the `post ID` so they can later search for their post (since it might take some time before its published)

After submitting a post, the USP pro delivers a URL like this together with the "Thankyou" message:
`mywebpage.com/submit-post/?usp_success=2&post_id=75796&form_id=74557`

I would like to use some sort of code to then also deliver the `post_id` from that URL string. I have found a way to deliver a `post id`, but it delivers the id for the main page URL (/submit-post/ in the one above)

I am a bit familiar with `functions.php`, `css` and some dynamic content.

Comment: can you share some code snippets you tried ??

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I tried several, but all of them were realted to this one $post_id = get_the_ID(); in some way. But I think the result is the same anyhow - they are not url related but realted to the actual page my form is placed at.